# Python descriptors not working in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, compatibility

This code produces a different output in `Python 2` and `Python 3`.

```
class Descriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print('read')
        return 1

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print('write')

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        print('del')

class C():
    a = Descriptor()

c = C()                                
c.a                                    
c.a = 3
del c.a
c.a

print('finished')
```

The output for Python 2 is:

```
read
read
finished
```

For Python 3 it is:

```
read
write
del
read
finished
```

Why is this working this way? How are `Python 2` descriptors different from `Python 3` descriptors?

This makes also no sense, because http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors clearly describes exactly the same as
http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors

(These are the documentations for `Python 2.7` and `Python 3.0`.)

Comment: (BTW, Python 3.0 and its documentation are obsolete and retired; don't use Python 3.0 or 3.0.1.  The current docs are at http://docs.python.org/py3k/ and the current release is 3.2.3.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: As Ned Deily accurately points out in the comments, the **reason** this happens is your class `C` is an old-style class on Python 2, since you haven't specified `object` or another new-style class as its base class.

---

Because on Python 2, you're creating a new instance attribute `c.a` when you do `c.a = 3` which hides the descriptor object located at `C.a`.

```
c = C()
c.a
c.a = 3
print c.__dict__['a']
print C.__dict__['a']
del c.a
c.a
```

gives:

```
read
3
<__main__.Descriptor object at 0x04625570>
read
finished
```

Comment: But this would mean, I couldn't use __set__ descriptors in python 2. And why is this different in Python 3?

Comment: Your class C is an old-style class in Python 2.  Change it to `Class C(object)` and Py 2 works the same as Py 3.

Comment: dammit! sorry for even posting this question. :-) I changed `Descriptor` to a new style class, but haven't seen that `C` isn't a new style class. Thank you Ned.